# Win7 and Joystick Logitech Wireless Gamepad F710

Tags: windows-7, game-controller, logitech-gamepad

I bought a [Logitech Wireless Gamepad F710 joystick](https://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/wireless-gamepad-f710/faq) but I can not make it work with Windows 7, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please install the [latest drivers for it, version 2.215.64](https://download01.logi.com/web/ftp/pub/techsupport/joystick/F710ConnectUtility_2.15.264.exe).